# Eclipse error when I debug project

Tags: java, eclipse

I use Eclipse for long time .I never seen this error, But now I see every time that I debug project. Sometime it occur even I don't do anything.

> Java was started but returned exit code=1
>   C:\Windows\system32\javaw.exe
>   -Xms40m
>   -Xmx384m
>   -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
>   -jar E:\Backup261010\Download\Android App Dev\eclipse\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
>   -os win32
>   -ws win32
>   -arch x86_64
>   -showsplash
>   -launcher E:\Backup261010\Download\Android App Dev\eclipse\eclipse.exe
>   -name Eclipse
>   --launcher.library E:\Backup261010\Download\Android App Dev\eclipse\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110502\eclipse_1406.dll
>   -startup E:\Backup261010\Download\Android App Dev\eclipse\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
>   --launcher.overrideVmargs
>   -exitdata 838_5c
>   -vm C:\Windows\system32\javaw.exe
>   -vmargs
>   -Xms40m
>   -Xmx384m
>   -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
>   -jar E:\Backup261010\Download\Android App Dev\eclipse\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar

What should I do

EDIT :

this is my `eclipse.ini`

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms64m
-Xmx512m
-XX:-UseCompressedOops
```

It's also have the same problem

Comment: are there spaces in your paths ie Android App... are they quoted?

Comment: have no space, I've install new eclipse (in other place) but still have same error

Answer (score 0):

This requires a little bit of Google-fu. I found:

[A similar Code Ranch question.](http://www.coderanch.com/t/503269/vc/Eclipse-start-but-return-exit)

[A similar Eclipse Community Forum question.](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/204384/)

See if those links help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, this issue is because of Java Heap Size. You need to increase your java heap size.

http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/06/6-common-errors-in-setting-java-heap.html

Answer (score 0):

as per your error log

> C:\Windows\system32\javaw.exe **-Xms40m -Xmx384m**

your eclipse heap size is too low ....try to increa the same in eclipse.ini and then check.

Comment: -Xms128m
-Xmx512m

is not enough ? It's also have the same problem.

Comment: what is ur machine RAM?...try to make it as -Xms512m -Xmx512m and see...also have u tried starting a diff workspace with clean option...check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030064/how-to-run-eclipse-in-clean-mode-and-what-happens-if-we-do-so