# Trouble to start eclipse ganymede

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am getting trouble to open Eclipse ganymede version for windows 32bit.

```
---------------------------
Eclipse
---------------------------
JVM terminated. Exit code=-1
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:PermSize=128M
-XX:MaxPermSize=256M
-Djava.class.path=C:\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.101.R34x_v20081125.jar
-os win32
-ws win32
-arch x86
-showsplash C:\eclipse\\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_3.3.101.v200902111700\splash.bmp
-launcher C:\eclipse\eclipse.exe
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library C:\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.0.101.R34x_v20080731\eclipse_1115.dll
-startup C:\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.101.R34x_v20081125.jar
-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin\..\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:PermSize=128M
-XX:MaxPermSize=256M
-Djava.class.path=C:\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.101.R34x_v20081125.jar 
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and then on again?

Comment: yes, tried restart also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple suggestions:

- if it never worked, try with a different JDK (try with a JDK5 for instance)
- if it was working:

  - try with an `eclipse.exe -clean` (see "[How to run eclipse in clean mode? and what happens if we do so?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030064/how-to-run-eclipse-in-clean-mode-and-what-happens-if-we-do-so)")
  - try with a separate fresh installation
- try also with a custom eclipse.ini like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659).