# JUnit error: Could not find or load main class (RemoteTestRunner)

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I've downloaded Junit version 4.10 and loaded the jar via the build path but I seem to get this error message when running a Junit test in Eclipse:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner
```

My Test class is the following:

```
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;



public class InternetConnectTest {

@Test
public void testConnectMethod(){

    InternetConnect net = new InternetConnect("www.google.com");
    assertEquals("Result", "www.google.com", net.url);


}

}
```

Comment: *Now included in the original question.

Comment: If anyone else stumbles across this - if you're running Eclipse on Windows try using "Run as administrator..." when you open Eclipse. Seemed to do the trick for me with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an Eclipse error message. It seems your installation is corrupted. Try using a fresh installation of Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick. I've been having to re-install quite a lot recently - Is Eclipse usually this unstable ?

Comment: As noted by @David, try simply restarting Eclipse before doing anything drastic like reinstalling, worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I came across this after I updated java versions: "junit: could not load main class 1.1".  Go into the eclipse external tools configurations, open the entry for the ant file you are running, then go to the JRE tab, and select "Separate JRE", also making sure your new jre is correctly listed in the Installed JREs...for me, this took care of it.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem.
I relaunch Eclipse with the "-clean" option, and it did the trick too.

Edit:
[How to run eclipse in clean mode? and what happens if we do so?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030064/how-to-run-eclipse-in-clean-mode-and-what-happens-if-we-do-so)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Before trying a fresh install i just restarted eclipse and it did the trick.