# How to clear the SpringSource Tool Suite cache?

Tags: java, eclipse, caching, maven, project

I have installed [SpringSource Tool Suite](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts) (STS) version 3. I created two Maven projects: a console application and a web Maven application. I tried to open `Main.java` in Eclipse, but without success. 
I tried to restart STS, but receive this error:

```
!SESSION 2012-06-09 09:13:29.626 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=3.0.0.201205010613-M1-e42
java.version=1.7.0_04
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product com.springsource.sts.ide
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product com.springsource.sts.ide

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-06-09 09:13:30.552
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.osgi.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.resume(InternalSystemBundle.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.launch(Framework.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected to find an object at table index: 1008
```

I suppose that I need to clear some cache. Is that correct? Where is it?

Comment: did you ever find a way around this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps you could solve it starting Eclipse with the `-clean` option

[How to run eclipse in clean mode? and what happens if we do so?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030064/how-to-run-eclipse-in-clean-mode-and-what-happens-if-we-do-so)

Answer (score 1):

Edit file "ECLIPSE_HOME\configuration\config.ini"
change

```
osgi.bundles=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.osgi_3.6.2.R36x_v20110210.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.200.v20100503.jar@1\:start
```

To

```
osgi.bundles=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.200.v20100503.jar@1\:start
```

More details Can be found [here](http://atealxt.appspot.com/article/20110309/eclipse_cannot_startup_when_update_to_helios_SR2.html)..

Comment: I thought your issue might be same.! 
I will look in stack again and try to solve. :)

Comment: can you please post your config.ini