# What happened to "Compile Prolog Code" (Alt+K) in the SICStus Eclipse SPIDER menu in Juno?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno, sicstus-prolog

I just upgraded from Eclipse Indigo to the Classic Eclipse 4.2 Juno, by downloading from this URL:

ftp://ftp.uninett.no/pub/eclipse/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.2-201206081400/eclipse-SDK-4.2-win32-x86_64.zip

I installed the SPIDER in Eclipse Juno, from this update URL:
http://www.sics.se/sicstus/update/

Now, when I start Juno, I am no longer able to use the shortcut ALT+K to compile the current Prolog code. The option is also removed from the SICStus menu provided by the SPIDER.

Can anyone please explain why this is happening, or how to deal with it?
I would like to compile my code without a lot of typing! Thanks.
I've tried using both the same workspace as before, and a completely new workspace.

EDIT: I'm on a Win7 64bit system, with a fresh Juno Classic installation (except the SPIDER plugin), and a brand new workspace.

EDIT2: Alt+K seems to appear for the first newly created or opened file, but when I do "File -> Open" on other *.pl files, the Alt+K option on the SICStus menu "moves" to work for ONLY this new file (and no longer for the other files). This behavior seems very weird to me.

EDIT3: After some support-answers from Per Mildner I'm able to get this "almost working", e.g. for freshly opened files, one at a time. I'm now waiting for him to come back from holidays in August, or for someone else to provide a better and more permanent solution to this weird problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused by an incompatibility between Eclipse 4.2 and earlier releases. The problem has been fixed in the latest version of SPIDER (0.0.42).

(I am the author of SPIDER)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!
I tried with a new workspace (on Win7), and still I couldn't see the Alt+K option, but after running through the "HelloWorld Cheat Sheet" it suddenly appeared.

Answer (score 0):

I stepped through Per Mildner's support check-list, and after item 2 I discovered that Alt+K works for the first prolog file freshly opened in a new session, but not for files from previous sessions, or files that are opened after the first one.

Here are the things to try, and after each step, verify whether the problem persists:

1. Restart Eclipse.
2. Create a new Prolog project in the old workspace, add some prolog
   files to it.
3. Use a new workspace.
4. start eclipse with the -clean option,
   e.g. [How to run eclipse in clean mode? and what happens if we do so?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030064/how-to-run-eclipse-in-clean-mode-and-what-happens-if-we-do-so)

My current "Work-around" for this on Windows7 (64bit) is to click inside the SICStus-tab close to the bottom of my eclipse window. This actually activate the ALT+K option for the current file in the editor.