# Error sign in Maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have this in my eclipse workspace:

[image]

As you can see there the main folder of the maven project has an error sign, even though it's subfolders contains no error.

- **Why do this happen?**
- **Could this possibly result with an error?**
- **Or could it possible be a bug?**

---

**Just for clarifications:**

This project doesn't seem to have any error and is working fine. But this error sign is bothering me, that maybe this error sign could possibly result with an error in the future. I just need an explanation on how did this happen?

Again, Many thanks to all of you..

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: window->show view->problems

Comment: @Scary Wombat, i cannot find the problem view as you've said. I'm using Eclipse Juno.

Comment: well I am not.  find out how to `show view` in Eclipse Juno

Comment: You should also be able to see the error on the markers view, which is already displayed on the far left of the bottom views in the picture.

Comment: @t0mppa, explored every views i have but still no error found. Just did some refresh and update on the project and everything goes well. anyways, thanks..

Comment: @Makudex, yes, I saw your resolution. That's great. Just saying that whatever is shown on the problems view is also apparent on the markers view, which you wouldn't have to spend effort digging out, as it was displayed on your screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be some error which is not being displayed in package explorer or project explorer. You can find it in `Problems` view.

Later you may right click project `Maven` > `Update Project`. If the symbol still exists, refresh the project using F5.

Comment: i cannot find the problem view. I'm using Eclipse Juno.

Comment: Goto Windows > Show view > Others. Search Problems and you get it.

Comment: I explored the problem view and found no error with the project. Just did some refresh and update project as suggested and it worked. Thanks James!

Comment: @wwwDELL, glad to know it worked! Thanks for accepting the answer. :)

Answer (score -1):

1. Hover that error sign and look if hint will popup. What does it says, if any?
2. Try to clean Eclipse cache. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11768339/2109067) solution, for example.

If Cleanup won't fix that:

1. Start new workspace.
2. Import yours project to that new workspace.
3. If it worked - try again with new workspace but with workspace settings, imported from initial workspace.

Comment: There's no error found after i hovered the project.

And about cleaning eclipse cache, how could i do that? Thanks.

Comment: Your suggestion to start new workspace won't help, as you can see i have many projects in the current workspace. And I don't want to work hard for that copying all my projects to another workspace :(

Comment: @AndréSchild, cache cleanup _actually_ was an answer to the question. See accepted answer. My answer was pointing to the wrong cache, though.

Comment: @wwwDELL "What does it says if any?" and "If Cleanup won't fix that" are not what is considered answers/solutions on stackoverflow

Comment: I've nothing to do with that @Andre Schild, maybe you we're referring to ankhzet.

Comment: @AndréSchild, by your's logic, `There could be some error which is not being displayed` is also `not what considered answer/solution on stackoverflow`. Actually `Hover that error sign and look if hint will popup. What does it says, if any?` states exactly same thing, but proposing instead of looking at `Problems view` to look at sign hint. In NetBeans problem-signs provided with verbose popup, don't known that Eclipse is different, but it worth a try.

Comment: @AndréSchild, looks like you confused suggestions with critics/clarification requests.