# Eclipse not responding while writing

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-oxygen

Ok so I installed Eclipse Oxygen a few months ago and it was working just fine til a month ago.I would start writing and in the middle of something Eclipse would stop responding for a few seconds and then continue and so on making it impossible to work with.I did all the updates and I searched for different answers online but couldnt find the answer.Help would be apppreciated

Comment: Try disabling the spelling checker

Comment: Still the same thing

Comment: Some of the solutions here may work [Clean out eclipse workspace metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768106/clean-out-eclipse-workspace-metadata) I've had the issue a few times over the years - often times nothing really makes it better and I end up downloading a new version and starting over moving my projects into the new workspace - which isnt too big a deal as long as you dont have a ton of servers defined.

Comment: Mine also currently does it, but it's with a web service implementation file thats a hundred thousand or so lines long.  It will pause for a few seconds when copy and pasting - dont ask why it's so long ;-)

Comment: I just downloaded another version and it still does that

Comment: Eclipse searches the code indexes for 'code proposal' suggestions (content assist) so rebuilding them as JGlass suggests is a good idea. Also, check that part of the configuration, may be some code recommenders can be disabled. It could get slow after index rebuilding but should get better after a while.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Treat it like a deadlock (except the part where you report it as one) and figure out what it's doing. https://wiki.eclipse.org/How_to_report_a_deadlock