# Eclipse IDE hangs when typing class

Tags: php, html, css, eclipse, ide

I'm using eclipse (zend studio 11), and it was working fine for quite sometime, but for two days when i type `class=` as soon as i hit the equals sign it takes about 10 minutes hanging, with no response, after that things just go back to normal.
Any ideas?

Comment: You can try some of these suggestions.  I do feel your pain, it hasn't happened to me in a while but its happened a few times. [clean out eclipse workspace metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768106/clean-out-eclipse-workspace-metadata)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend Studio 11 it's old and unsupported. To find whats going on see this wiki page https://wiki.eclipse.org/How_to_report_a_deadlock. In most cases problem appear with broken DLTK index, so:

1. Close Zend Studio
2. Drop WORKSPACE_LOC/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.dltk.core.index.sql.h2 and/or WORKSPACE_LOC/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.dltk.core.index.lucene
3. Open Zend Studio and wait for indexing

Anyway I strongly suggest switching to upcoming Eclipse Photon. Since this release code completion is asynchronous.