# Eclipse will not debug anymore after a crash of the computer

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

Last night when I'm developing an Android app using Eclipse, the computer suddenly out of order and showed a blue screen.

After restarting, open Eclipse, and when I continue the development, I found out that Eclipse will not show any error message even if I type anything wrong.

For example, I type **$^&((^(*&$GFKGHlkgvfekigfe** in the activity, Eclipse shows nothing, just like the code is correct LOL

How can I re-enable the auto debug function? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or try to run Eclipse in clean mode. Please see the following discussion: [How to run eclipse in clean mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030064/how-to-run-eclipse-in-clean-mode-and-what-happens-if-we-do-so)

Answer (score 0):

You able to Automatic Build by

1. Go Eclipse project menu
2. Choose `Build Automatically`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Linger, I think it does.  Re-enabling automatic builds will allow Eclipse to detect syntactically incorrect errors as the user is writing the code.

Comment: @Alexander, you are right.  My comment was from before the edit.  Now that I have read it after the edit it makes sense and should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your project.  In Eclipse, select your root project folder in the project navigator, then go to `Project > Clean... > OK`.  You can also clean all projects by selecting the `Clean all projects` radio button in the clean dialog.