# Can not open eclipse after SDK updates

Tags: android, eclipse

Can someone read what is a problem why i can not open eclipse? I updated android sdk tools and I installed new API. I restarted my computer and eclipse stiil do not work. This is Log from .metadata. Could someone read what is the problem?

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.StatusHandlerRegistry.<init>(StatusHandlerRegistry.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.StatusHandlerRegistry.getDefault(StatusHandlerRegistry.java:91)
        at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.getStatusHandler(StatusManager.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:189)
        at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:231)
        at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager$StatusManagerLogListener.logging(StatusManager.java:305)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.RuntimeLog.logToListeners(RuntimeLog.java:160)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformLogWriter.logged(PlatformLogWriter.java:100)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.safeLogged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.logPrivileged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:205)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:178)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogServiceFactory.java:65)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceImpl.log(ExtendedLogServiceImpl.java:87)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.LoggerImpl.log(LoggerImpl.java:54)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.Log.log(Log.java:62)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.log(WorkbenchPlugin.java:813)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.handleException(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.handleException(SafeRunner.java:75)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:44)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$54.run(Workbench.java:2412)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Comment: When stuff like that happens I start eclipse with the "-clean" parameter for deleting all cached workspace meta data. It usually fixes the problem. However, it can happen that a workspace gets corrupted beyond repair. In that case you probably need to create a new one :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158889/eclipse-fails-to-start-after-crash). About halfway through his .log he has the same message you are receiving. Following the first answer may work for you.