# Eclipse terminated without warning.

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception

My eclipse terminated without any warning. I tried to open it but it gets terminated immediately when it loads in the start itself. I don't know what the problem is.

Can someone help me with this?

My `eclipse.ini` file is:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\javaw.exe
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-Declipse.buildId=v22.3.0-887826
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

and I got this error in my .log file the last time I tried to open it up:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2014-01-22 11:17:18.368
!MESSAGE Error occurred during status handling
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.StatusHandlerRegistry.<init>(StatusHandlerRegistry.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.StatusHandlerRegistry.getDefault(StatusHandlerRegistry.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.getStatusHandler(StatusManager.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager$StatusManagerLogListener.logging(StatusManager.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.RuntimeLog.logToListeners(RuntimeLog.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformLogWriter.logged(PlatformLogWriter.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.safeLogged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.logPrivileged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogServiceFactory.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.ExtendedLogServiceImpl.log(ExtendedLogServiceImpl.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.log.internal.LoggerImpl.log(LoggerImpl.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.Log.log(Log.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.log(WorkbenchPlugin.java:813)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.handleException(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.handleException(SafeRunner.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$54.run(Workbench.java:2412)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Comment: And legions of psychic, omniscient StackOverflowers descended upon @Monysha's computer to fix the issue...

Comment: Run the eclipse command from a console or command line.  Is there an error?

Comment: JVM running Eclipse may be crashing. Do you see files named like hs_err_pid<somenumber>.log in your file system? If true they will have some clues about why JVM is crashing.

Comment: There is no error or warnings or no popups at all.... it just terminates .... doesnt even go inside the file... loads for 2 seconds n just terminates

Comment: In your workspace folder there is a .log file that will probably give you details about the error happening.

Comment: Someone plz help me out

Comment: As you've been asked, are you seeing crash files left around? Have you looked at the .log file in the workspace's .metadata folder for more error information?

Comment: I had similar problem. I used the solution mentioned in  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158889/eclipse-fails-to-start-after-crash  .  I renamed the ./metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench  to ./metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench.temp  and it restarted eclipse.