# Java eclispe doesn't load - "An error has occured. See the log file"

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration

My Java eclipse (Kepler) doesn't load. When I try to launch, I get the following message:

"An error has occured. See the log file.
C:\Program Files\eclipse\configuration\1434441085545.log."

I tried EVERYTHING: deleting the eclipse library, deleting .medata library from workspace, changing workspace, -clear from the command line. Nothing is working for me. I can't add the log file here because there are too many rows...

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-06-16 11:18:00.746
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
```

config.ini:

```
org.eclipse.update.reconcile=false
eclipse.p2.profile=epp.package.standard
osgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/workspace
osgi.framework=file\:plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.9.1.v20130814-1242.jar
equinox.use.ds=true
eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.M20130911-1000
osgi.bundles=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.400.v20130327-2119.jar@1\:start
org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info
eclipse.product=org.eclipse.platform.ide
osgi.splashPath=platform\:/base/plugins/org.eclipse.platform
osgi.framework.extensions=
eclipse.application=org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench
eclipse.p2.data.area=@config.dir/../p2
osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: What does the log file say?

Comment: There must be something useful in the log file that you can copy/paste here. Otherwise we have nothing to go on ..

Comment: !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-06-16 11:04:46.050
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.equinox.registry (141).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.Activator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.equinox.registry.
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)

and so on...

Comment: I have limited chararcters when I comment

Comment: @AlonBenNatan  look near the end of the log or look for exceptions. And I'm quite sure you did not yet try everything ;-) Please reformat your answer, mark the error message as code and remove typos. People will be more happy to help you when everything looks "tidy"

Comment: I can give you the headlines for each paragraph. Will it help?

Comment: Maybe try with the last stacktrace available in the log? And edit your question, you will be able to paste more characters there.

Comment: this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158889/eclipse-fails-to-start-after-crash

Comment: I entered the last stack trace in my question. I can't insert the entire file, it is too long. Anyway, I re-installed my eclipse. I still haven't defined work space, so .metadata answers are irrelevant (I think).

Comment: Do you have `config.ini` file in the configuration directory?

Comment: Yes. The file exists.

Comment: Java version could be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding below lines in your `eclipse.ini` ignore some of the existing lines in your eclipse.ini

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms128m
-Xmx1024m
```

Comment: Now I get this message: The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library.

Comment: Did you check your existing eclipse.ini file whether it already contains launcher configuration?

Comment: Yes, sorry my bad. I didn't copy your new rows right. However, when I did, still the same answer - "An error ocured, see log file"

Comment: I even tried to download a different version of eclipse and I got the same error. It is probably something in my PC.

Comment: I don't enough - "reputation" to chat

Comment: which java version you are using 
you can update below line in eclipse.ini with your jdk version

-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6

Comment: Did you try deleting following file from workspace

YOUR_WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap

or
C:\path\to\eclipse\eclipse -clean

Comment: OK, i did it. Just deleted everything on my computer that had the word 'eclipse' on it, re-installed, and it worked. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: @AlonBenNatan So please either answer your own question with this solution or decide if it is better to delete this question completely