# Eclipse won't start after .ini edit

Tags: eclipse

Fisrt I got an error **"eclipse out of memory error and gc overhead limit exceeded"** and,

Then I tried looking for the answer, and then found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23080078/eclipse-crashes-with-a-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded-error/23112487#23112487).

After I edited the .ini just like Silvio's answer my eclipse won't start.

It just disappear after chosing workspace folder.

**Edit :**
I already tried opening a new eclipse and still eclipse won't start.

Comment: Can you show us your .ini file

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu :  -startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
  --launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m

Comment: Can you just remove both the occurrences of `--launcher.XXMaxPermSize 256M`  and add `-MaxPermSize=256m` at an end and try.

Comment: still won't start.

Comment: Mistake in my earlier comment. It should be `-XX:MaxPermSize=256m` at the end after `Xmx512m` same line. Can you try it now.

Comment: but still remove both the occurrences..?

Comment: yes, do remove both occurences...

Comment: but still remove both the occurrences..?  **Edited** I Guess it has something to do with windows registry. Is it..?

Comment: Now it says failed to create java virtual machine..

Comment: okie..can you please post your current. ini file in your question

Comment: Fixed., I delete .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench on workspace folder to fresh start eclipse.. Found it here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158889/eclipse-fails-to-start-after-crash) diffrent problem, same answer.

Answer (score 0):

Entries in the eclipse.ini file :

```
-startup plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-showsplash org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize 256m
--launcher.defaultAction openFile
-vmargs
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-XX:PermSize=1024M
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024M
```

I hope fix your problem.

Comment: Just copy and paste in my eclipse .ini right...? @PraveenKumarVerma **edited**:still won't start..

Comment: No, Check -XX : PermSize and -XX : MaxPermSize  is changed