# Eclipse type hierarchy not always working

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-indigo

When I want to see implementation of some interface through <kbd>F4</kbd> (type hierarchy) or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> (quick hierarchy) or implementation of a method, I can't see it! Problem is, that it works in 90%, but I have few cases when interface and implementation are in same package and eclipse doesn't recognize it via type hierarchy. Any suggestions?
Got Eclipse Indigo SR2.

Comment: Can you provide a sample class structure that reliably fails in Eclipse? We could then test it.

Comment: Dose this apply to your own hierarchies only or to Java classes also? If the first: do you have any compiler errors in your code? Try re-building...

Comment: No errors in workspace..I can't certainly tell that the problem is only within my classes...as I said, it works in 90% maybe more, but I have 1 specified class that doesn't work anyhow. Also I need to tell, that my colleagues have no problems with this class.

Its common interface nothing special. Also, when I'm in implementation, I can ctrl+click on method to redirect into interface without any problems, but when I check type hierarchy for implementation, the only super class I'm seeing is Object.

Comment: I have the same problem. Probably is triggered (in my case) by computing hierarchy for a scala type. This corrupts the indexes. If I clean them up it works till I compute a hierarchy for one of my scala classes. I'm using `eclipse.buildId=4.5.0-vfinal-2016-12-13T10:59:29Z-Typesafe`

Answer (score 54):

I had this same problem and fixed it by deleting the Eclipse index cache files located in .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core.  Delete all .index files and savedIndexNames.txt.  Do this while Eclipse is not running and then restart.  This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: There is probably a bug in eclipse leading to cache corruption during application crash.

Comment: Cool .. this fixed the issue! I was wondering why I was suddenly not seeing any subclasses in the type hierarchy.

Comment: Someone should log a defect to eclipse if this keeps happening.  #notIt

Comment: I take it all back.  It worked, EXACTLY ONCE!  I'll see if I can create a simple, repeatable example and log a bug.

Comment: Thanks! I've just deleted the whole dir `org.eclipse.jdt.core` and it worked (Eclipse Luna 4.4.0).

Comment: By the way, the .metadata directory is located in your workspace root folder.

Comment: It works in 2021-09 too, FWIW.

Answer (score 1):

Use Eclipse clean mode for deleting caches, look here: [How to run eclipse in clean mode? and what happens if we do so?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030064/how-to-run-eclipse-in-clean-mode-and-what-happens-if-we-do-so)

Sometimes is good to use clean mode to prevent these types of problems.

Comment: Worked for me on Neon Release (4.6.0). I ran in clean mode by adding -clean as first line of my eclipse.ini file.

Answer (score -4):

I also had this problem and fixed it.
The reason of this problem is that when the eclipse is running, I reinstall the JDK from 1.8 to 1.6.
So I close eclipse, install JDK 1.8 again, then it's OK!
May it will be helpful for others.