# Eclipse hangs on reverting resources

Tags: eclipse, maven, svn, rcp, subclipse

I use eclipse Indigo, subclipse 1.10.x and javaNL. Whenever I try to refresh my project in eclipse, it gets stuck at Reverting Resources 0% and Computing Update Requirements 0%. I try to kill eclipse and reopen the project and it still does the same.  I do not understand why this happens. It started happening recently. Before it was working fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Question:**  I do not understand why this happens

**General Answer:** http://www.ihateeclipse.com/

(I may share this opinions and dont think Eclipse should be called a IDE but that wont fix your problem - hence lets proceed with possible workarounds).

**Possible Workarounds:**

1.) Starting eclipse in clean mode [How to run eclipse in clean mode? and what happens if we do so?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030064/how-to-run-eclipse-in-clean-mode-and-what-happens-if-we-do-so). (This solved aprox. 80% of my continuously returning 'I messed up my own state' issues I experienced).

2.) If that doesnt help - you would have to stop eclipse, identify the according files (or just any files holding such information) and delete them manually, then restart eclipse. Like I still encounter issues with my "Search Type" (Ctrl+T) and have to delete the files like described here [Eclipse type hierarchy not always working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16354028/eclipse-type-hierarchy-not-always-working) (unfortunately I don't know anything about files regarding your current issue - so feel free to downvote my "answer" since its not directly answering your question).

The best things I found about "the full reset" seem to be: http://letsgetdugg.com/2009/04/19/recovering-a-corrupt-eclipse-workspace/ or http://blog.pdark.de/2011/09/02/restoring-a-corrupted-workspace-in-eclipse/ (Note: I haven't verified the described behaviors).

3.) Recreate Workspace - delete any eclipse belongings like the `.metadata` folder and keep only belongings of your project (e.g. sources, resources etc.). Then create a new eclipse project based on you existing project sources).

4.) If Steps 1-3 failed consider reinstalling Eclipse (include above Step 3 in this process again) or switching to a proper IDE that can at least handle its own state.

5.) I experienced rare cases where in the end such things were triggered by me rather than occurred magically out of nowhere by eclipse - I don't see any possibility on how you could manage that in your case unless you messed around with the eclipse source itself).

Hope this helps - Even thus the SO community is big I experienced way better results asking the eclipse developer community directly when it came to such specific issues (you however oftenly get a link to a open Bug ... that they created because of your question) and ended up "just importing into a new eclipse workspace from existing sources" whenever I experienced such issues lately (It takes me about 5 minutes to checkout our sources, start Eclipse with -clean as default and import existing Maven projects solving any eclipse-only issue - while each of those eclipse-issues can take days to be solved without any further advantage for my daily business)

Comment: #2 fixed this problem for me. I deleted .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources and then reimported the projects.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will help any one but I had the same issue. Some links advised me to delete my metadata, which I did not want to do.

What fixed it for me was:

1. I have multiple eclipse workspaces, I manually closed my eclipse using the System Monitor/Taskbar as it wouldn't let me close as it was hanging.
2. I switched workspaces and it seems to run fine. So I switched back to the one that was hanging and the problem seemed to have gone.

Comment: Worked for me, too. Killed eclipse -> Renamed my orig. workspace -> Restarted eclipse -> Closed eclipse again -> Renamed my orig. WS back -> Restarted eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:
Go to to your workspace instalation, and manually delete the target directory under your maven projects (dont worry , maven will create another one when compiling). This removed my stuck Eclipse state  (thread) in "Revert sources", always at 0%.

Answer (score 1):

this helped me:
delete files "*.snap" under org.eclipse.core.resources in 
worskpace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/

and share project again (setup SVN settings)

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally checked in target files to SVN. And the target files were huge ans hence it was stuck on reverting resources. Once I deleted those target files from SVN this issue never happened.But JBA's answer is pretty comprehensive so I will mark that as a right answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue, and I just quickly cancel the "Rerverting Resources" task while it's in "waiting" mode when restart Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

This should work to 100% and helped in my case (no other tried solution worked):

1. Go to "Eclipse > Help > About Eclipse IDE > Installation Details
2. Uninstall the following packages "Subclipse", "Subclipse Integration for Mylyn", "Subversion 1.14 JavaHL", "Subversion Revision Graph", "SVN Client Adapter".
   [pluginsToUninstall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjxVa.png)
3. Go to the marketplace and install "subclipse" again.
4. Rightclick on your project > Team > Refresh/Cleanup

You are welcome. :)