# Katalon Studio: The project may be inconsistent

Tags: katalon-studio

I'm struggling with Katalon Studio. After manually copy-pasting some files in the Include and Keywords folders, deleting the bin folder and Libs folder, I finally managed to destroy my test project.

> A class file was not written. The project may be inconsistent, if so
>   try refreshing this project and building it

which sounds very much like an [Eclipse Build Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17154360/eclipse-build-error-a-class-file-was-not-written-the-project-may-be-inconsiste), but I've got no problem of free disk space.

**How can I "Refresh this project and build it" from Katalon Studio?<sup>1</sup>** The Katalon community appears to be a little [toxic](https://forum.katalon.com/t/can-someone-tell-how-to-build-deploy-katalon-project-from-devops-point-of-view/18496/5) about it, and I don't want to end up like that poor guy.

Refreshing the project with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> does not solve the issue. I have assumed that content in Libs and bin is not sacred, since it is default-ignored by the Katalon Studio built .gitignore.

---

<sup>1: or, how do I un-do the screw up?</sup>

Comment: Katalon Studio IDE is based on the Eclipse, so no wonder. Have you tried `Project > Refresh` or `File > Cleanup`?

Comment: Refresh didn't help, while `Project > Close and Cleanup` did. I did tried closing Katalon Studio and re-open it, but it didn't solve it either. Choosing the option, on the contrary, worked.