# Eclipse doesn't start after upgrading from Juno to Kepler

Tags: eclipse, upgrade, eclipse-kepler

I followed the instructions on page 
http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse%3F
but unfortunately eclipse does not start anymore. I can choose a workspace and then it stops with error "An error has occured. See the log file ....metadata.log

The log file shows a bunch of errors which are:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2013-08-22 06:43:34.234
!MESSAGE Unable to create class 'org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.CommandServiceAddon' from bundle '283'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: Unable to process "CommandServiceAddon#init()": no actual value was found for the argument "IEclipseContext".
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.reportUnresolvedArgument(InjectorImpl.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:874)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2013-08-22 06:43:34.250
!MESSAGE Unable to create class 'org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.CommandProcessingAddon' from bundle '299'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: Unable to process "CommandProcessingAddon.commandService": no actual value was found for the argument "ECommandService".
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.reportUnresolvedArgument(InjectorImpl.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.resolveRequestorArgs(InjectorImpl.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2013-08-22 06:43:34.250
!MESSAGE Unable to create class 'org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.util.BindingProcessingAddon' from bundle '302'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: Unable to process "BindingProcessingAddon.commandService": no actual value was found for the argument "ECommandService".
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.reportUnresolvedArgument(InjectorImpl.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.resolveRequestorArgs(InjectorImpl.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2013-08-22 06:43:34.281
!MESSAGE Unable to create class 'org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.HandlerProcessingAddon' from bundle '299'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:877)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.HandlerProcessingAddon.processActiveHandler(HandlerProcessingAddon.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.HandlerProcessingAddon.postConstruct(HandlerProcessingAddon.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    ... 27 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-08-22 06:43:34.343
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.ExpressionContext.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/contexts/IEclipseContext;)V" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) of the current class, org/eclipse/ui/internal/services/EvaluationService, and the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) for resolved class, org/eclipse/e4/core/commands/ExpressionContext, have different Class objects for the type se/e4/core/contexts/IEclipseContext;)V used in the signature
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationService.<init>(EvaluationService.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.init(Workbench.java:1529)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$39(Workbench.java:1511)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$58.run(Workbench.java:2672)
```

Is there any eclipse guru out there who could help me with that ?

Thank you.

Comment: does it work with a new (empty) workspace?

Comment: Yes I tried (with option -clean) a new empty workspace, same error.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem today after upgrading from Juno to Kepler.  I solved it as follows:

Make a backup of the file:

```
eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator\bundles.info
```

Then hand-edit the original file, finding and removing any duplicate packages.  For each duplicate you find, retain the one with the most recent version number.  E.g. mine had lines like:

```
org.eclipse.core.commands,3.6.1.v20120814-150512,plugins/org.eclipse.core.commands_3.6.1.v20120814-150512.jar,4,false
org.eclipse.core.commands,3.6.100.v20130515-1857,plugins/org.eclipse.core.commands_3.6.100.v20130515-1857.jar,4,false
```

In this case I removed the `3.6.1` line, and kept the `3.6.10` line.  Be careful to only remove lines where the name before the first comma is identical.

After this, [start Eclipse with the `-clean` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030064/how-to-run-eclipse-in-clean-mode-and-what-happens-if-we-do-so) and you should be up and running.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem today after some updates, I solve it restarting eclipse with the `-clean` option on the command line.

Comment: It's obvious to try that and I did already - sorry. Unfortunately I din't meniont. The Workspace Launcher shows up, I choose an existing workspace and then a small windows pops up: "An error has occured. See the log file ..\.metadata\.log which shows more errors, including the ones from initial post.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21195843/3924261) of [simonp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2323695/simonp) I've solved this problem. In my case (using Linux) the file was here:

```
/opt/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info
```

This command could help you finding the duplicated lines (it says you which lines are duplicated and how many times):

```
cat /opt/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info | cut -d "," -f 1 | uniq --count | sort -n | tr -s " " | grep -v "^ 1"
```