# Cannot find error on ADT

Tags: java, android, adt

Screenshot:

[image: http://postimg.org/image/bkz7gb385/]

I found error appearing on packages, but I cannot find it on whole `.java` files. I am using adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130522

May be someone ever got same problem

Comment: Tried cleaning the project?

Comment: You can open the Problem view of eclipse to locate where is the problem

Comment: Try to see if any of the answers/comments are helpful here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19787919/sudden-weird-errors-on-a-project

Comment: Most oftenly this is because Eclipse just sucks... currently i am forced to work with that piece of crap and can build my 3 webservices as well as the two JEE components using maven but eclipse shows all of the packages/ project red while none of the classes has any issues nor is there a problem in the problems-view. Id recomend ignoring whatever eclipse says because its wrong in 90% of the cases or switch to a real IDE like Intellij which is defently worth its money :)

Comment: Make sure there is no missing library error in your BuildPath. Check out the library.

Comment: FunkTheMonk : I've done it, but still error.
ThaiTran : there are many problem on problem view, but I didn't find the problem from that library. 
ᴍarounᴍaroun : thanks.. I still try all the answer.
user1902288 : that why you dislike eclipse
GrIsHu : it is a library..

Thanks very much for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the missing libraries and jar files from ur project properties
Also check if there is android-support-v4.jar in your build path.