# Eclipse loading box pops up then quickly disappears, why isn't it loading?

Tags: java, eclipse, loading

I have been using eclipse for a few months for a java course at school on my laptop. It's about 3 years old and probably on its last legs, and now whenever I click the eclipse shortcut on my desktop, or try to load Eclipse through any other means (going through the start menu) the loading box quickly appears in the centre of my desktop then disappears, and the program doesn't load. 
I'm experiencing this with one other program (a diplomacy computer game interface), but not other more strenuous programs (CIV 4), so my question is:

Have any of you experienced this before, and do you have a guess as to what the problem is and how to fix it?

I've also tried disabling my anti-virus firewall but it doesn't change anything.

Thanks!

Comment: Try looking at the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is an error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting eclipse with the **clean** option:

```
eclipse -clean
```

Using this option will force eclipse to reinitialize its cache. That might help.

Comment: Haha I'm sorry I'm quite new at this, how would I enable the clean option? Do I have to open Eclipse through the cmd window? Until now I've been clicking on the shortcut or opening from my start menu, and since the program doesn't load I'm not sure how I'm going to open with the clean option enabled!

Comment: There are several alternatives.  Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030064/how-to-run-eclipse-in-clean-mode-and-what-happens-if-we-do-so)