# Error Creating a new Glassfish 4 server with Oracle Tools for Kepler

Tags: glassfish-4, eclipse-kepler

I installed Oracle Tools for Kepler with no problem. But when I want to create a new server and fill in the directory to the server (which is valid, C:/glassfish4/glassfish), nothing happens. I can only click 'back' or 'cancel'.

attached image for better understanding

Thanks in advance

http://es.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=x3tkea&s=8#.U2jz6vl5NUU

http://es.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2n0ldtu&s=8#.U2j1_Pl5NUU

Comment: This looks like a problem with the JDK. Please add a screenshot of your **installed JRE preferences**.

Comment: my installed JRE preferences are:

http://i57.tinypic.com/2a5auds.png

http://i62.tinypic.com/123l18l.png

Answer (score 0):

This is really a weird error/bug/whatever. I have exactly the same setup on my home workstation and it works if I choose **jdk1.7.0_55**  or **Default JRE** as JDK in the dialog. It doesn't work when I choose **jre7**.

You can try to select **Default JRE** and see if this works.

Another option is to try a clean start of Eclipse. Edit the `eclipse.ini` file located in your Eclipse install directory and insert `-clean` as first line.

If you have downloaded a multi-language version of GlassFish 4, the problem may be related to that. You then may try it with the english only version.

If this also doesn't help you can also add the server runtime manually in the folder `<WORKSPACE>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\` in a file named `org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs` (if it doesn't exist, create it). It should look similar to this:

```
eclipse.preferences.version=1
module-start-timeout=300000
runtimes=<?xml version\="1.0" encoding\="UTF-8" standalone\="no"?>\r\n<runtimes>\r\n <runtime id\="GlassFish 4.0" location\="C\:/glassfish4/glassfish" name\="GlassFish 4.0" runtime-type-id\="org.glassfish.jst.server.runtime.glassfish4" server_definition_id\="org.glassfish.jst.server.runtime.glassfish4" timestamp\="0" vm-install-id\="1399586723676" vm-install-type-id\="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType">\r\n    <map key\="generic_server_instance_properties" sunappserver.rootdirectory\="C\:/glassfish4/glassfish" sunappserver.runtimeName\="GlassFish 4.0"/>\r\n  </runtime>\r\n</runtimes>\r\n
```

**(The format looks a bit weird with the \r\n but this should be correct.)**

- **You have to change the `vm-install-id` in this configuration, look for the ID of your JDK in the file `<WORKSPACE>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.jdt.launching.prefs`. There should be an entry with your JDK. Copy the `vm-install-id` from this entry.**
- Make sure to have the right path to your GlassFish installation in that file.

After saving the file, start Eclipse and try to create a new server. The runtime should then be available when you choose GlassFish 4.0.

**See also:**

- [How to run eclipse in clean mode? and what happens if we do so?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030064/how-to-run-eclipse-in-clean-mode-and-what-happens-if-we-do-so)