# eclipse Kepler building issues >>NonLockingJarFileClassLoader

Tags: java, eclipse, metadata, classloader

I had to force to quit eclipse once. After that I continuously face bunch of problems.

- First one is `can not write metadata for 'MyProject'`.
- I can not remember but second one is Eclipse is tried to write .indexes folder but failed because of permission. So I opened permission
- Finally, I meet this

Error message is below :

```
Error during build of project [MyProject]
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Spring Project Builder' on project 'MyProject'.
org/apache/xbean/classloader/NonLockingJarFileClassLoader
```

I do not have any clues of it. is there anyone who experienced this before?

Thanks for your answers in advance:D

Comment: First aid when encountering errors after a force quit of Eclipse is cleaning workspace data. Have you tried starting eclipse with the `-clean` flag? See this question for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030064/how-to-run-eclipse-in-clean-mode-and-what-happens-if-we-do-so

Comment: @StefanWinkler -clean does not work. I also use that option some times(for instance, when eclipse hang while loading), but this is little different. workspace loading has no problem but after that it shows a pop up. In the popup of detail box I found the message

Comment: Is there any more detail in the "Errors" view? Usually there's a stack trace associated with that kind of error messages.

Comment: @StefanWinkler I guess that is all I got. Usually, when eclipse collision happens it pops up Apple report windows(where is details button and I get informations about eclipse process). However in this case, eclipse process does not die, but just show internal popup and unable to compile.(Sorry for my poor explanation)

Comment: @StefanWinkler Is there other file or something I can check stack?

Comment: Can you check `<workspace_dir>/.metadata/.log`?