# Eclipse Project --> Clean goes forever

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using Eclipse Juno and whenever I give Project --> Clean, the process goes on forever and never completes. I will have to cancel the request every time. Also , Run As --> Android Application also takes forever and never displays the next screen to choose the device on which we want to run the app.Please help

Comment: close eclipse, reopen, close every project open that is not needed for your project, and try again

Comment: If the suggestion of @LenaBru does not help. Try to start eclipse with clean mode. This will clean the caches for each plugin and might help. Refer to this answer to know how to do this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2030092/1423083

Comment: Thanks @LenaBru! Reopening Eclipse fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

close eclipse, reopen, close every project open that is not needed for your project, and try again