# Eclipse juno hangs startup

Tags: java, eclipse

Yesterday I coded a bit and then exit eclipse as I normally do. When I started it today, without doing any sort of eclipse/java updates, it hangs as soon as it starts and nothing can be done. I have tried reading the log and searching on google, but there is so much stuff there that I don't know what to search for. All hits on google send me away to useless sites.

Here is the log that I found in workspace/.metadata/.log

EDIT: Sorry, I thought that eclipse clears its logs on startup. I removed 2 files, .log and .bak_0.log and then restarted eclipse and funnily enough that fixed the problem :D. So remember children, when your eclipse stops working, try cleaning the logs :D.

Also this is my fresh log file, there is one error left that I would like to take care of while I'm at it.

http://pastebin.com/biSDSFTS

Comment: Clear the log file, try opening Eclipse, and then check the log file again. Then maybe something will stand out (and post it here too).

Comment: you may also try the magical http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030064/how-to-run-eclipse-in-clean-mode-and-what-happens-if-we-do-so

Comment: Removing the old logs fixed the problem, but there is one more error thats left. This is the one that google didn't help me with.

Comment: this? https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73002

Answer (score 0):

Tried all the options, nothing worked. So I finally figured out the solution:

- I removed all JRE installations in my `C:\Program Files` and `C:\Program Files(x86)` folders.
- Installed a new JDK 7 package, copied the fullpath of the `JDK7\bin` folder and appended it at the end of the "Path" variable under 'Environment variables' of my Windows 7 pc.
- Then restarted everything, so it worked.