# Clean and Start eclipse from command prompt

Tags: eclipse, cmd, jadclipse

What is the command to start the eclipse from command prompt. After installing jadclipse I am not getting the jadclipse option under preferences, and read somewhere that starting and cleaning from command prompt will solve the issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run eclipse in clean mode? and what happens if we do so?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030064/how-to-run-eclipse-in-clean-mode-and-what-happens-if-we-do-so)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this in the command line

**cmd_line_path>** eclipse.exe -clean

Answer (score 1):

1. Navigate in your cmdprompt to the eclipse installation folder using `cd`
2. execute `eclipse.exe [calling arguments]`

Another approach would be to add the eclipse installation folder path to your PATH environment variable
 open `cmd` and execute `eclipse.exe [calling arguments]` directly

Comment: without the -clean argument this will just start eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Go to your eclipse ide installation(application.exe)folder type cmd and run below this command.
eclipse.exe -clean this is perfectly to solve my problem.

Comment: Now does this improve on the answer from 6 years ago?