# Eclipse Plug-ins develop: Plug-in A use a Class in Plug-in B, after exporting as jars and installed in to eclipse, NoClassDefFoundError occurs

Tags: eclipse, plugins, osgi

Plugin A uses a class,ClassB, which is from Plugin B.When "run as eclipse application", everything goes well; however, when PluginA adn Plugin B are exported as Jar, and install into a new eclipse platform, they run well independently, but crash when the codes reach the line where Plugin A uses the ClassB.

error log: ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

In plugin org.jboss.vpe.browsersim.eclipse, there is BrowserSimLauncher.java in the package org.jboss.vep.browsersim.eclipse.launcher;

In plugin org.ayound.js.debug.core, there exits a java file "JsLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java", and I put BrowserSimLauncher.launchBrowserSim(startUrl);

into it, this means I've used previous plugin's class 'BrowserSimLauncher' in the latter plugin.

I also do all the"dependencies things", including adding lines to latter plugin's manifest.mf:

```
Import-Package: org.jboss.tools.vpe.browsersim.eclipse.launcher
```

and to previous plugin's manifest.mf:

```
Export-Package: org.jboss.tools.vpe.browsersim.eclipse.launcher
```

In the development environment, both plugins compiles successfully, when "run as eclipse application", things goes well, and the latter plugin can sucessfully call  `BrowserSimLauncher.launchBrowserSim(startUrl);` ;
however, when I exported both plugins as several .jar files, and copy them into the /plugin folder of another eclipse directory, start the eclipse, both plugins can run well independently, but the plugin fails to call `BrowserSimLauncher.launchBrowserSim(startUrl);`.  and the error log show as follow:

```
    !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2015-01-06 16:29:03.817
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Launching index.html".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/tools/vpe/browsersim/eclipse/launcher/BrowserSimLauncher
    at org.ayound.js.debug.launch.JsLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launch(JsLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:858)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:707)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1222)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.tools.vpe.browsersim.eclipse.launcher.BrowserSimLauncher cannot be found by org.ayound.js.debug.core_2.2.0
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 6 more
```

the latter plugin(js.debug.core) can't find the previous plugin(browsersim.eclipse)!

Comment: Start Eclipse specifying the '-clean' option to get it to rebuild the plugin dependencies data.

Comment: oh my! Problem solved! Why.....!! I've spent 2 days on it, and you solve it in two minutes....Anyway, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just copy plugins in to the Eclipse 'plugins' directory then you need to specify the '-clean' option when you start Eclipse to get it to rebuild the plugin dependencies cache.

You can specify '-clean' on the Eclipse command line or in the eclipse.ini file (here it must be before any -vmargs line).

It is safe to always specify -clean but it will slow down the Eclipse start a bit.

### supplements:

Just startup eclipse with option "-clean", problem solved. Details are from [reference article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030064/how-to-run-eclipse-in-clean-mode-and-what-happens-if-we-do-so):

What it does:

> if set to "true", any cached data used
>   by the OSGi framework and eclipse
>   runtime will be wiped clean. This will
>   clean the caches used to store bundle
>   dependency resolution and eclipse
>   extension registry data. Using this
>   option will force eclipse to
>   reinitialize these caches.

How to use it:

- Edit the `eclipse.ini` file located in your Eclipse install directory and insert `-clean` as the first line.
- Or edit the shortcut you use to start Eclipse and add `-clean` as the first argument.
- Or create a batch or shell script that calls the Eclipse executable with the `-clean` argument. The advantage to this step is you can keep the script around and use it each time you want to clean out the workspace. You can name it something like `eclipse-clean.bat` (or `eclipse-clean.sh`).

(From: http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t61566.html)

Other eclipse command line options: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html