# Eclipse Side-by-Side Editor Behaviour

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

At some point Eclipse has decided to add a load of whitespace when dragging one editor tab to the side of another.

Is it possible to get the old behaviour back in newer versions of Eclipse?

Eclipse 4.4, with nasty whitespace:
[image]

Eclipse 3.7, without the pointless whitespace above the tabs:
[image]

**Update**

After @GGrec's suggestion, the white bar is much smaller, but still present. Is this at all avoidable, or is this just the way Eclipse 4.4 is?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a workspace metadata bug. You're using your old workspace with the new Eclipse.

You can also notice the ugly black thick line under your workbench actions.

To fix this, go to `Preferences -> General -> Appearance`. Change your theme, then change it back. [Do an Eclipse restart with `-clean`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030064/how-to-run-eclipse-in-clean-mode-and-what-happens-if-we-do-so) while you're at it.

Comment: Thanks - the amount of whitespace is reduced now, but still not gone entirely like in the first of my screenshots. Is there still some whitespace by design in 4.4?

Comment: @Deejay There really shouldn't be. With a clean Eclipse, and a clean workspace, you wouldn't have this issue.

Comment: Even in a fresh workspace, Eclipse 4.4+ does have a small white bar above side-by-side editors. If you look at the far right side of that space you'll see the Minimize/Maximize/Restore buttons for managing the *total* editor area (the group of side-by-side editors).

Comment: Thanks @E-Riz - that's what I'm seeing. I'm guessing there's no option or theme that can be set to remove this?

Comment: @Deejay You could take your chances [with this highly customizable eclipse theme plugin](https://github.com/jeeeyul/eclipse-themes)

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1.** Uninstall,

**Step 2.** Clean application data:
For example, In my computer: `%userprofile%` == `C:\Users\vy.vy-pc\`

Delete folder: 
`C:\Users\vy.vy-pc\AppData\Roaming\Spring Tool Suite` and 

`C:\Users\vy.vy-pc\AppData\Local\Spring Tool Suite`
[image]
[image]
**Step 3.** Reinstall your Eclipse.