# I can't type "(" (left parenthesis) anymore in the editor in Eclipse

Tags: linux, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, keyboard, installation-package

I've been using Pydev/Eclipse in Linux for days, but after installing some new software(a bunch), I can't type "**(**" in the editor anymore.

Any idea's to as what could be the problem?

It has something to do with this, sorry about the noobness, but I still can't comprehend all the software I'm learning:

[image]

And what is this and how to get rid of it?:

[image]

Here is an error message I think is relevant:

```
A conflict occurred for CTRL+SHIFT+T:
Binding(CTRL+SHIFT+T,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.python.pydev.editor.actions.pyShowBrowser,Python Show Global Tokens (Editor),
        Python Show Global Tokens (Editor),
        Category(org.python.pydev.ui.category.source,PyDev - Editor,PyDev editor category,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@5644fc26,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.python.pydev.ui.editor.scope,,,system)
Binding(CTRL+SHIFT+T,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(com.python.pydev.analysis.actions.pyGlobalsBrowserWorkbench,Python Show Global Tokens (Global),
        Python Show Global Tokens (Global),
        Category(org.python.pydev.ui.category.source,PyDev - Editor,PyDev editor category,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@4b064f09,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    com.python.pydev.contexts.window,,,system)
Binding(CTRL+SHIFT+T,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.navigate.open.type,Open Type,
        Open a type in a Java editor,
        Category(org.eclipse.ui.category.navigate,Navigate,null,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@b2efe5a,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the first screen-shot we can see that multiple commands were assigned to Shift + 8.

Try these:

- Go to `Windows > Preferences > General > Keys` in the search bar type Shift + 8 try to unbind this command or at least change the context of the command in **When** combo box.
- Restart eclipse and/or restart eclipse with clean workspace.

Links:

[How to run eclipse in clean mode? and what happens if we do so?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030064/how-to-run-eclipse-in-clean-mode-and-what-happens-if-we-do-so)

[Keeping Eclipse running clean](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t61566.html)

[How to manage keyboard shortcuts in Eclipse and why you should](http://www.eclipseonetips.com/2010/02/03/how-to-manage-keyboard-shortcuts-in-eclipse/)