# Why my eclipse is running so slow

Tags: java, eclipse

I don't know whats wrong with my eclipse. its running so slow.
it takes at least 10 minutes to open. when Start server it is also taking long time.I tried multiple way.

I am on Windows 7,

eclipse LUNA (4.4.0)

I am using maven and spring framework and running jboss server.

I have 8 GB of RAM.

my eclipse.ini look like that

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
```

I have changed Xms and Xmx value from

-Xms128m

-Xmx128m

to this

-Xms1024m

-Xmx1024m

But I am having the same issue,
It was working fine but after few days it become slower and slower.
Please help.

Comment: Windows 64 bit you're using right? 'cause 32 bit will only take 2+GB of RAM even you have 8GB RAM.

Comment: There could be an endless list of reasons for this. You should also provide additional information like: eclipse version, any new plugins that you installed before it got slower etc. We used to see problems with javascript validation and the maven builder slowing down our IDE (that was in version 3.4).

Comment: Try launching eclipse from command prompt with memory arguments. eclipse -Xms 4048M -Xmx 4048M and look for any log on command prompt.

Comment: Did you try using a clean workspace? You could try running eclipse in clean mode: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030064/how-to-run-eclipse-in-clean-mode-and-what-happens-if-we-do-so)

Comment: One more thing I used to do, I'll close Dynamic Web project as much as possible. 'cause building workspace will validate JARs inside web application which will take much time. So closing un-used project would help a little.

Comment: as other mentioned, could be because of plugin, try to disable recent plugins you have installed and restart until it goes to normal

Comment: @link I do it now and then, but it does not effet

Comment: @ Pasupathi I have only one Dynamic project

Comment: The following link can be helpful:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/how-can-you-speed-up-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Add -Xverify:none to your eclipse.ini file.

It will cut down your Eclipse startup time considerably.This will tell the VM not to validate all the .class files it is loading

Comment: Undo the previous changes and try -XX:MaxPermSize=128m and -Xverify:none

Comment: -Xquickstart this may help you..Once try this

Comment: This is a bad idea.  Class verification takes next to no time.  Disabling it certainly won't fix the OP's 10 minute startup problem. (That is caused by something else.)  And if you do somehow happen to have a class with a verification issue in your Eclipse installation, class verification will avoid random memory corruption and undiagnosable JVM panics.

Answer (score 0):

try removing unwanted plugins from the eclipse.. since these plugins cause unnecessary memory consumption  you will definitely see some improvement. I have faced this issue, after removing some plugins,my eclipse got real faster..

Comment: I have 8 GB of ram and I am using just single plugin which spring framework

Comment: check in task manager, and see what is the cpu usage, if it is higher,, then eclipse will be slow

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Eclipse plug-in 'Optimizer for Eclipse'. It really helped me to boost my Eclipse start-up.

It can update your settings by itself (change heap size, suggest the latest eclipse/jdk version, and more).

Link : https://zeroturnaround.com/free/optimizer-for-eclipse/

Answer (score 0):

Disable unwanted plugins during startup.

[image: Eclipse Startup Shutdown Settings]