# Eclipse change theme

Tags: java, eclipse

Yesterday when I close eclipse everything was fine.
Today I open eclipse and it looks very strange.
Some buttons are missing.... and other visual changes.
How can I change it back to default look.

Btw I'm using:
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Mars Release (4.5.0)
Build id: 20150621-1200

[image: Eclipse]

Comment: What os are you using

Comment: Win 10 ..............

Comment: Have you tried [launching eclipse in clean mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030064/how-to-run-eclipse-in-clean-mode-and-what-happens-if-we-do-so)?

Comment: No... I'll try now...

Comment: @SandeepChatterjee thanks dude, now it's normal :)

Comment: @KiKo - You are welcome. I have posted this as an answer. Consider marking it as accepted which will mark this post as solved. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you can **[launch eclipse in clean mode](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t61566.html)** by issuing

```
eclipse -clean
```