# Compilation error in Java: cannot find symbol

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I currently have a class `Printer` which is accessed statically, but when I try to compile the project after adding a function to the class I get `error: cannot find symbol`.

I know this is generally caused by typos, out-of-scope references and bad declarations, but the odd thing here is that the old methods work just fine.

This code has *exactly* the same structure as my own code, and it works:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Printer {
    private static String errorTitle;
    private static String regularTitle;

    Printer(String regularTitle_) {
        errorTitle = "Some error: ";
        regularTitle = regularTitle_;
    }

    public static void printError(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(errorTitle + e.getMessage());
    }

    public static void print(String message) {
        System.out.println(regularTitle + message);
    }
}
```

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Printer("Message: ");

        try {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            //This works
            Printer.print(e.toString());

            //This generates a cannot find symbol error when compiling
            Printer.printError(e);
            //     ^ here
        }
    }
}
```

The complete error message is:

```
[javac] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Javaprojects\MyProject\alpha\build
[javac] C:\Javaprojects\MyProject\alpha\src\Main.java:35 error: cannot find symbol
[javac] Printer.printError(e);
[javac]        ^
[javac] symbol: method printError(Exception)
[javac] location: class Printer
[javac] 1 error
```

This works fine if I change `Printer.printError(e)` to `Printer.print(e.toString())`.

What can possibly be the cause of this? Could it be that I am referring to some sort of cached version of the compiled class?

Comment: I see no errors here.

Comment: I have cleaned the project and recompiled it several times. The error persists. I'm trying to figure out the cause for this, but I am completely out of ideas

Comment: @sweerpotato show us snapshot

Comment: Try removing your  `import java.io.*;` statement.

Comment: i had run this code online and it works,
https://ideone.com/0rH4yJ

here is the link to the output

Comment: Snapshot? Screenshot?
@Arvind I have, didn't change anything

Comment: @sweerpotato yes screenshot of your error

Comment: One clue is that the complete error tells us that the missing symbol is the name of the method, not the name of the parent class.

Comment: What ``javac`` version do you use?

Comment: I actually managed to solve this now. I changed the import from `import utility.*;` to `import utility.Printer;`. Why was this the problem?

Comment: @sweerpotato There is no line ``import utility.*;`` and you was instructed by Jordi Castilla to remove all your * imports.

Comment: This was an example I wrote on ideone as an MC(V)E. I did remove the imports and I cleaned the project as instructed

Comment: The code in your question wasn't a MCVE. It misses the part which leads to failure, thus isn't complete and verifiable.

Comment: So how do you suggest I make an MCVE with the V?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code [is ok](https://ideone.com/wQKXXY), program flow does not, but not the problem here. 
Only thing not necessary are the imports,

---

Remove imports:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
```

Clean the project, and rebuild it.

---

If this does not work, [**start eclipse in clean mode**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030064/how-to-run-eclipse-in-clean-mode-and-what-happens-if-we-do-so), clean and rebuild project again.

---

**ADD-ON**

> The problem is solved. In fact, it were the * imports which caused the compilation error.
> *I could access `Printer.print(String)` but not `Printer.print(Exception)`.
> **Why was this the case?***

As long as I cannot find any `Printer` class in util, lang or io packages, only scenario I can imagine you get this error, is: Eclipse was importing a previous version of your `Printer` class where the method `Printer.printError(Exception)` didn't exists yet, sum this to imports causing bad building so you have problem persisting for several cleanings.

Comment: I have tried removing imports, cleaning the project and rebuilding it. The problem still persists though

Comment: The problem is solved. In fact, it *were* the * imports which caused the compilation error. If this would be my question I'd give this answer the check.

Comment: @JordiCastilla why were the * imports causing problems? I could access `Printer.print(String)` but not `Printer.print(Exception)`. Why was this the case?

Comment: As long as I cannot find any `Printer` class in `util`, `lang` or `io` packages, only scenario I can imagine you get this error, is: Eclipse was importing a previous version of your `Printer` class where the method `printError(Exception)` didn't exists yet, sum this to imports causing bad building so you have problem persisting for several cleanings...

Comment: I see! Thank you very much for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

> What can possibly be the cause of this?

Unclear.  It could potentially be many things ... including some kind of misconfiguration or corruption of your IDE's workspace, etc.  Or an IDE bug.

> Could it be that I am referring to some sort of cached version of the compiled class?

It could be.

---

The code you have shown us seems to consist of two classes in the same source file.  This is legal, but not recommended, and it could be part of the cause of your problems.

I suggest that you put the two classes into separate source files (if they aren't already).

---

Apart from that, I don't think there is enough information for a proper diagnosis.  And I see from the comments that people are **unable** to reproduce your problem.

(I don't see how removing the unnecessary imports would make any difference.  There is no `Printer` class in those packages that could be imported by accident.)

---

A couple of off-the-wall ideas:

- You haven't declared your own class called `Exception`, have you?
- You aren't being bitten by a "homoglyph" problem in your source code, are you?

Comment: I haven't declared my own class called Exception, and I'm sure this isn't a homoglyph problem. Good suggestion though!

Comment: What about two classes in one source file?

Answer (score 0):

Just rename your class Printer to something else and it should work.