# Cannot Create Openshift project in Eclipse

Tags: node.js, eclipse, jboss, openshift, enide

[image: 'Create new project' wizard window]

I have updated all the plugins provided by JBOSS, recommended in OpenShift->Get started page..
Yet I dont see, Openshift option in Create new project wizard window.. Anyone please help me out here.
I am using Enide (Eclipse-Mars).

Comment: it might help you : https://dzone.com/articles/openshift-how-create-web-0

Comment: thanks man.. but i have already gone through that.. M having different situation..

Comment: You can check in Help -> About Eclipse Platform -> Installation Details that you have definitely installed the plugins.
One more thing to try: in the first line of eclipse.ini put the following: `-clean` see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030064/how-to-run-eclipse-in-clean-mode-and-what-happens-if-we-do-so)

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed JBossTools (more precisely OpenShift 2 plugin inside JBossTools) in Eclipse, you can do the following:

Window ->  Show view -> Other... -> JBoss Tools -> OpenShift Explorer

Now you can see the OpenShift view. Click on add new server, provide your credentials. Then right click on your new added account, and choose:

New -> Application...

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Peter.. Still there is a problem.. In show view.. under JBoss Tools-> Project Archieves (only one option and no OpenShift Explorer)

Comment: Try reinstalling the plugin, it should be there. Note that there is OpenShift 2 and OpenShift 3 plugins, you need the "2".