# Why am I unable to show Ecplise-Plugin after successfully installed?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, ide, toad

I am unable to use `Eclipse-Plugin` after `install` it into Eclipse IDE.

Same thing happen with all Most time with me, while going to `install` any plugin either it is from `MarketPlace` or from `ZIP`.

**For example,** just right now i have installed Toad-Eclipse-Plugin & after installing it while i am going to open it from

```
Window -> Open Perspective -> Other
```

i am unable to show it over there into list.

So , finally i am unable to use it.

Same scenario i feel before with while installing Maven-Plugin.

Can anybody guide me here what is the exact way to install any plugin into eclipse and use it in a right manner ? ( especially Toad-Eclipse Plugin )

> I have tried both way,
>
> 1. `Installing` from Market Place
> 2. First Download `Zip` and extract it and add to then `Install New Software`...

My Current Perspective after Installing Toad-Eclipse-Plugin is as per below screen shot : 
( that installed plugin needs to be here but not come up why ? )

[image]

*If Any Help Appreciate....!!*

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, both the approaches which you've mentioned should work.

1. Installing from Market Place
2. First Download ZIP and extract it and add to then Install New
   Software...

Then, eclipse has to be restarted to apply the new changes.

However, sometimes eclipse won't load new plugins due to OSGI registry caching issues. This can be solved by launching eclipse in clean mode.

To launch eclipse in clean mode. Go to the terminal.

```
eclipse -clean
```

In mac OSX, go to terminal

```
cd  /eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS
./eclipse -clean
```

To understand more about clean mode:
[How to run eclipse in clean mode? and what happens if we do so?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030064/how-to-run-eclipse-in-clean-mode-and-what-happens-if-we-do-so)