# Eclipse will only run a non-existing project

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to have Eclipse run my project called **ScrapeMax**.
Whenever I try to run this project, instead Eclipse will run a project called **Wiki Expander**. *Wiki Expander does not exist within the workspace and is not imported in Eclipse*.

The following does not solve the problem:

- Main is ofcourse included in the class.
- Main is not capitalised.
- Main is ofcourse public.
- Choosing "Runs As/Java Application" runs Wiki Expander instead of ScrapeMax.
- The main-class is called Startup, and the file is called Startup.java.
- I've tried deleting all Run configurations and recreating it for ScrapeMax. It doesn't help.
- The Run configuration does ofcourse involve the proper main class.
- Cleaning all projects didn't solve it.
- /eclipse -clean didn't solve it.
- Removing the project and importing it again didn't solve it.

How do I make Eclipse stop running Wiki Expander, og run ScrapeMax like I want it to?

Comment: Probably Eclipse configuration files are corrupted. Delete/remove project and import again.

Answer (score 0):

seems like eclipse cached wiki project,You need to clean up your eclipse cache.[check out here that how to clean eclipse cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030064/how-to-run-eclipse-in-clean-mode-and-what-happens-if-we-do-so)