# Restarting eclipse that was clean started

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a handy shortcut on my Windows desktop to clean start eclipse with the `-clean` command provided in the shortcut target as below:

```
C:\eclipse\eclipse.exe -clean
```

When I launch the eclipse by running this shortcut, what happens when I perform a restart? Does it restart clean or does it preserve the cache?

(I do not have the `-clean` command in the eclipse.ini file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run eclipse in clean mode? and what happens if we do so?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030064/how-to-run-eclipse-in-clean-mode-and-what-happens-if-we-do-so)

Comment: @Edwardth It doesn't talk about what happens on restart.

Comment: When you click restart in eclipse it seems like the parameter `-clean` gets lost. So it's better to add `-clean` in eclipse.ini

Comment: @Edwardth My goal is not to clean start the eclipse each time. I wanted to figure out how eclipse handles restarting when clean started.

Comment: I guess your question is: What does eclipse restart actually do?

Comment: @Edwardth Kind of. But this might be a special case as the eclipse was clean started in first place.