# Nothing within Eclipse is loading

Tags: eclipse

I have a very strange issue which I can't find any specifics on.

Basically, eclipse starts up fine, but doing anything gives me a permanently-spinning loading icon.

I tried:

Window > Preferences - Every option I click on does not load it's respective page, but I can still expand options and click around the window.

Help > Install new software - I can use the dialogue fine but when I enter a URL or downloaded repo, the pane where it shows me installable content just says "pending..."

Right Click > New > Project - I try to create a simple java project and after creating it the dialogue box goes inactive (cannot click any buttons) and I get the loading icon.

I'm not really sure how to diagnose this problem other than googling "nothing in eclipse is working". I get no error log or anything. When launching through a terminal I get the following output:

```
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is initialized.
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Logback config file: /home/jacob/new_workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration/logback.1.6.2.20150902-0002.xml
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://911.fwk620351183:1/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://911.fwk620351183:2/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Initializing logback
```

Comment: Can you start the eclipse with -clean flag and see if it works...check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030064/how-to-run-eclipse-in-clean-mode-and-what-happens-if-we-do-so

Comment: @saurav - no luck. It still loads up just fine but everything in it is broken

Comment: Do you have lot of projects opened ?...if yes then i suggest to close them and try again...eclipse has lot of reasons to go haywire...if it has lot of custom plugins and lot of projects opened..then the experience is not smooth.. may also uninstall unnecessary plugins/features installed...

Comment: This is a fresh install of eclipse on a new OS (Ubuntu 16.04). I've tried reinstalling it 5-6 times (keplar, luna, mar,s neon) to no avail. I have no projects and no plugins - but I can't add any either.