# Extremely slow filesystem access in Eclipse using SSD

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a project with lots of files. After switching to an SSD disk, things became impossible, its extremely slow. I reinstalled, upgraded to a new version (oxygen) but nothing changes.

For example, a refresh of workspace can take 10 minutes. A single file renaming, 5 minutes. But sometimes (it happens occasionally) these operations are really fast.

My OS is `Debian 4.9.30-2+deb9u5 (2017-09-19) x86_64`.

Eclipse build information:

`Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)
Build id: 20171005-1200
OS: Linux, v.4.9.0-3-amd64, x86_64 / gtk 2.24.31`

Before the SSD disk switch, I had no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue. What fixed it for me was running Eclipse in clean mode, to clear out cached data. The first time you do `eclipse -clean` it takes ages, but then it's fast again. You should only have the `-clean` flag on once, not every time you run it.

Take a look at this answer for details: [How to run eclipse in clean mode? and what happens if we do so?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030064/how-to-run-eclipse-in-clean-mode-and-what-happens-if-we-do-so)