# Eclipse IDE is very slow after resuming Windows

Tags: eclipse

Since a week or two, Eclipse becomes very slow after resuming Windows:

- Scrolling becomes very slow: the scrollbar and line numbers scroll at a different speed than the text. Then I need to wait for the text to catch up.
- Typing is very slow. I'd guess there's a 500ms delay
- Running code is very slow. The unit tests for my current project typically take around 5 seconds. After resuming Windows, this is systematically over 20 seconds.
- Opening or saving a sourcecode file takes longer (several seconds)

However, navigating menus doesn't seem to be slower than before.

Restarting Eclipse doesn't help, though I notice it starts up quicker than after a clean boot, which makes me believe it doesn't shut down completely.

Other Java apps don't appear to be slower.

In case the problem can't be found, is there some way I can force Eclipse to restart cleanly?

Comment: Re forcing Eclipse "to restart cleanly", see the chosen answer for this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030064/how-to-run-eclipse-in-clean-mode-and-what-happens-if-we-do-so

Comment: If that doesn't help look in the Error Log ( **Window -> Show View -> Other... -> Error Log** ) and update your post if there are any relevant messages/failures.

Comment: Restarting eclipse cleanly (by adding the -clean option to the shortcut) works perfectly.  Thank you.