# Eclipse and Tomcat 8.0.35 app ERROR: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm running a Java app in Eclipse EE Oxygen 32 bit in a 64 machine since the program will be transferred to a 32 bit machine later. The app is connected to mysql installed through Wampserver, and the server I'm using in the app is Apache Tomcat 8.0.35. When I run the app in "Run as> Run on Server" inside Eclispe. I get the following error message in "Console":

```
 Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1372)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1042)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.checkContextClassLoaders(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:90)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:63)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How can I debug that?

Comment: I must use it because of compatibility with other libraries connected to the project, but would the version (32 bit Eclipse in 64 bit machine) be causing the problem?

Comment: No, see my answer: just restart Tomcat then try again.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The java code is totally portable across 32-bit and 64-bit platforms, doesn't make sense to use a 32 bit Eclipse version.

**To solve your issue, just restart the Tomcat server to get rid of the older cache then try again.**

If still doesn't work:

1. Restart Eclipse
2. Clean up Eclipse working directory (see @nitind comment).
3. Run Eclipse in clean mode (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030064/how-to-run-eclipse-in-clean-mode-and-what-happens-if-we-do-so))

Comment: You can also clear out the work directory from the instance's context menu in the **Servers** view.

Comment: I went to "tomcat/bin" and run "shutdown.bat" (I'm using Windows) , and than run "start.bat". But still the same error returned.