# Java Eclipse Application won't open when I click on it

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse has worked well just until now, but now I cannot get in when I click on the application. Nothing pops up, and the program just won't load (I restarted computer multiple times). After clicking bunch of things, I went inside plugins folder of the eclipse, and I clicked on org.eclipse.equinox.launcher which opened up a screen called "platform launcher" and when I loaded one of the work spaces it got me to a eclipse platform page, then suddenly two errors popped up saying:

"An internal error occurred while showing an internal error. You are recommenced to exit the workbench..."
"An internal error occurred during: Building workspace" (and 4 lists, "Building workspace", "Java heap space", "Java heap space" and "Update dynamic Java sources working sets").

At one point I also got out of memory error or something like that so I changed the eclipse configuration setting (xmx and xms) but I still cannot get inside the program.

Please share any possible solutions...I'm desperate...

For reference, I have 10.0GB RAM

Answer (score 0):

Try running eclipse from command line using eclipse -clean. Check below Url 
[How to run eclipse in clean mode? and what happens if we do so?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030064/how-to-run-eclipse-in-clean-mode-and-what-happens-if-we-do-so)

If workspace issue, you can also
Try deleting the metadata folder and restart it. Keep a backup before you delete. This folder generally stores all the workspace settings