# Eclipse - Unexpected error loading extension: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.compositeRepository

Tags: eclipse

Suddenly I was not able to check for Eclipse updates and every connection to an online repository was failing do to the following error, visibile in `ECLIPSE_WORKSPACE/.metadata/.log`

```
    !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository 4 0 2020-05-15 09:58:58.981
    !MESSAGE Unexpected error loading extension: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.compositeRepository
    !STACK 0
    java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @59ec6f70 wants to load interface org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider. A different interface with the same name was previously loaded by org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @58c5820f. (org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @58c5820f, parent loader 'platform')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that running Eclipse in clean mode was the key to solve this issue: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030064/how-to-run-eclipse-in-clean-mode-what-happens-if-we-do-so)'s there more info about using that mode.