# Why can't I change persective from Java till C/C++ in Eclipse 2021-03?

Tags: java, c, eclipse

I'm trying to change persective from Java till C/C++ because I'm going to program C-code.
But when I select `C/C++`, then I'm still on Java perspective.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

It still looks that I'm using Java persective.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [clean mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030064/how-to-run-eclipse-in-clean-mode-what-happens-if-we-do-so)?

Comment: @Izruo No. What is that?

Comment: I linked an SO question that explains this more thoroughly than I can in a comment.

Comment: @Izruo Sounds like a bug from Eclipse. I have been using C and Java at the same Eclipse IDE on linux, but on Windows, it seems not to work properly.

Comment: I have no problems with C/C++ and Java (and several languages more) with Eclipse on Windows and on Linux. Why do you think the perspective is still Java, and not C/C++? The project seems to be a non-C project.

Comment: Which version of Java is being used to run Eclipse? They might not be installed properly (the missing icons, the <> around the Perspective name), or something else may be preventing them from being loaded.

Comment: @nitind OpenJDK 11 is installed from AdoptOpenJDK

Comment: Still, something suggests that the C tools aren't loading properly. You might want to reinstall with the C++ package as your starting point, and then add the Java tools to it to help iron out any issues.